# Why doesn't my homemade isset function in javascript completely work?

Tags: javascript, scope

In a book trying to illustrate global/local variable scope it used this example to convey the concept:

```
test();

if (isset(bar)){ 

    alert('bar must be global!');

}else{

    alert('bar must be local!');

}

function test(){

   var foo = 3;
   bar = 5;

}


function isset(varname){

    return typeof varname != 'undefined';

}
```

Right now the if returns the alert 'bar must be global.', which makes sense because the variable passed to the `isset()`, bar, in this case is global. But why doesn't the if statement return the alert('foo must be local'); when you pass lets say when you pass `foo`
in the isset function.

Comment: Because there's no declared symbol "foo" when you call `isset()`. If you called `isset(foo)` from *inside* the "test" function, it'd be set.

Comment: Because you're only calling `isset()` once with `bar` as a parameter.

Comment: I know that in theory that makes sense. But shouldn't the `else` fire?

Comment: No. You're asking the question "Is bar defined". The answer is yes so the `else` doesn't get examined.

Comment: But I am asking lets say instead of bar, you use foo. In theory shouldn't the else return, because their is no global variable.

Comment: No. You'll get an error because `foo` is undefined. Check your console when you run the script. It won't even call `isset(foo)` because `foo` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't used the var keyword, the variable is defined on global scope and still exists after executing test function. This is explained more thoroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470494/1744702).

Answer (score 2):

"bar" was not declared anywhere in your function test(). Javascript then assumes it's a global var.

To make sure your don't make these kind of mistakes, may I suggest you use :

```
"use strict";
```

Put that line at the beginning of your file. It will prevent a lot of errors as presented here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

It will prevent undeclared vars to act as global vars